# My fowards do not seem to work in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an issue with an apache .htaccess redirection on a laravel site
My forwards do not seem to work
here is what I want:
Foward www to non-www [www.ReplaceMe.com](http://www.ReplaceMe.com)  to   ReplaceMe.com
Foward HTTP to https     http://ReplaceMe.com   to  https://ReplaceMe.com
Foward non-trailing / to add trailing /   https://ReplaceMe.com   to  https://ReplaceMe.com/

so the result would be.
https://www.ReplaceMe.com/about-us   TO  https://ReplaceMe.com/about-us/

But it does not seem to be working.

Below Code i am using now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
               <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
                   Options -MultiViews -Indexes
               </IfModule>

               RewriteEngine On

               # Handle Authorization Header
               RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
               RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

               # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
               RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

               # Send Requests To Front Controller...
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
               RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
               # www to non-www
               RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ReplaceMe\.com$ [NC]
               RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ReplaceMe.com/$1 [R=301,L]
               # http to https
               RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
               RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

As far as I know, this should work.  Can anyone spot my Issue?